# finding given amount of prime number

Tags: c++

The wrote this program that is supposed to find a given number (n) of prime numbers, beginning with 2. I can't seem to find the issue, Im not getting any error messages, however, I am not getting the any output at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include <forward_list>
#include<vector>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <regex>
#include<random>
#include<stdexcept>

using namespace std;
bool is_prime(int a);

int main()
{
    cout<<"Give me the number of primes you want: \n";
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    vector<int> primes;
    int i = 2;
    int count = 0;
    while (n < count)
    {
        if (is_prime(i))
        {
            primes.push_back(i);
            count++;
        }
        i++;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++)
        cout<<"Prime number: "<< i + 1 << "\t"<< primes[i] <<endl;

}

bool is_prime(int a)
{
    if (a <= 1)
        return false;
    else if (a == 2)
        return true;
    for (int i = 2; i < a; i++)
    {
        if (a % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;

};
```

Comment: This seems like a good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Even some simple [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) should help you find the problem.

Comment: Presumably the value `n` entered is positive.   `count` is initialised to zero.  This means `n < count` is false as the `while` loop starts, so the body of that loop is never executed.

Comment: Change `while (n < count)` to `while (count<n)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bug is here:

```
int count = 0;
while (n < count)
```

What do you think happens when `(n < count)` is evaluated?

Usual suggestions for prime number detections:

1. Your loop only needs to test for divisibility up to `sqrt(a)`.
2. Your loop only needs to test for divisibility with odd numbers (after checking explicitly for the `2` case)

That is:

```
int stop = (int)sqrt(a);
for (int i = 3; i <= stop; i+=2)
{
  …
```

3. And if you really want to be performant, since you are accumulating primes into a vector, you really only need to test `a` for divisibility with the primes you have already confirmed.

Comment: wow I feel stupid, been up for 8 hours studying and completely misread it (brain fart), obviously it should be while n > count. Thanks for the help everyone, and I agree I should be checking its divisibility only for the prime numbers already found, as that would be more efficient. Im a beginner and just wanted to get it to work first. Appreciate the help Selbie, couldn't have asked for more.

Comment: @jack.b - I want you to learn how to use the debugger, set breakpoints, and use the watch window to inspect variables.   A debugger (such as the one built into almost all IDEs) could have found this issue in 5 seconds.  You almost always just click "debug" instead of "run" in some IDE menu/button.  You would have stepped over the code line by line and observed the while loop block not getting run at all after the `n < count` evaluation. It would have been obvious.

Comment: Im currently using a mac, from what it seems Xcode is the only viable option to code using c++. Im currently studying using Stroustrup PPP, I haven't gotten to the debugging chapter yet, though I believe its in the next chapter. From the research I did, you basically put a break point using the debugger, and from that point you can " walk through" the program line by line. Ill definitely use that next time, as you said, it would have revealed the bug quite quickly. Once again appreciate the help selbie.